Breakpoints Not Binding in Shared Libraries During Remote Debugging with GDB and VS Code
Description:
I'm experiencing an issue with remote debugging using GDB and VS Code where breakpoints in shared libraries are not binding correctly. Below are the details of my setup and the steps I have taken:
Setup:
Development Environment: VS Code on my laptop (Ubuntu)
Target Device: Raspberry Pi
Debugger: gdbserver running on Raspberry Pi, GDB Multiarch on laptop
Project Structure:
    Main executable: ${workspaceRoot}/build/rpi/usr/bin/my-executable
    Shared libraries located at: ${workspaceRoot}/build-output/lib

{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Attach to gdbserver",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/build/rpi/usr/bin/my-executable",
            "miDebuggerServerAddress": "192.168.1.100:1234",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb-multiarch",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Load shared library symbols",
                    "text": "set solib-search-path /home/user/projects/my-project/lib"
                }
            ],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "additionalSOLibSearchPath": "${workspaceRoot}/build-output/lib",
            "miDebuggerArgs": "${workspaceRoot}/build-output/lib",
            "logging": {
                "engineLogging": true,
                "trace": true,
                "traceResponse": true
            }
        }
    ]
}

Problem:
Despite setting the solib-search-path and ensuring that the shared libraries are compiled with debug symbols using the -g flag, breakpoints in the shared libraries are not binding. The breakpoints in the main executable work fine, but those in the shared libraries are ignored.
Steps Taken:
Ensured Debug Symbols: All shared libraries are compiled with the -g flag.
Set solib-search-path: Added set solib-search-path /home/user/projects/my-project/lib to the setupCommands.
Used additionalSOLibSearchPath: Set the additional symbol search path to ${workspaceRoot}/build-output/lib.
Configured Debugger Arguments: Added miDebuggerArgs with the path to the shared libraries.


If you stop at a point after the shared library has loaded and delete then reset the breakpoint does GDB place a breakpoint where you expect (use info breakpoints to check).  Also, has GDB spotted the shared library load?  Use info sharedlibrary to check.  Can you force a breakpoint in the shared library using break file:line syntax (not a long term solution, but will confirm GDB can see the file and place b/p there).

If I set the breakpoints "manually" with gdb, I can add the to .so files but they are not recognized. I used info sharedlibrary to see the .so files, but my target .so file don't show up there so I tried to add him with sharedlibtrary /path_to/lib.so, but when I want to print or info it again don't show up. So my problem is that I can't add this lib.so file to gdb ....
